# SQLite select query to get one row from multiple rows have same id

Tags: sqlite, select, duplicates, row

I'm trying to get one row from table that have an id column that duplicate in several rows of a SQlite database, but I am getting all rows in table.

This is my table creation and selection query.

```
CREATE TABLE IMAGES ( MID INTEGER , IMAGE BLOB, ID INTEGER );


SELECT DISTINCT ID, IMAGE  FROM IMAGES;
```

This what I get

```
mid | image | id
 1  |  m1   |  1
 2  |  m2   |  1
 3  |  m3   |  1
 4  |  m4   |  2
 5  |  m5   |  3
 6  |  m6   |  3
```

And this what i want

```
mid | image | id
 1  |  m1   |  1
 4  |  m4   |  2
 5  |  m5   |  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose the correct columns

```
SELECT min(mid) FROM images GROUP BY id;
```

Then you need to use that to select the correct rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, IMAGE  FROM IMAGES WHERE mid in (SELECT min(mid) FROM images GROUP BY id);
```

Otherwise the records from the GROUP BY, could be made up from any (or last) of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT applies to all the SELECTed columns, i.e., you get each unique combination of `id` and `image` in the data.

To control which columns get deduplicated, use GROUP BY.
You also have to specify which image you want for each ID; if you don't use MIN(), you get a random image:

```
SELECT id, MIN(image)
FROM images
GROUP BY id;
```